# how to change subdomain Buckets url to subfolder amazon

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

how can i change my Buckets from :
https://myname.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com

to :

https://s3.amazonaws.com/myname

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do anything. [virtual-hosted style](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-path-deprecation-plan-the-rest-of-the-story/) and the `global S3 endpoint` work automatically.